# pymysql: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I have been banging my head against this wall for a while now. I can't get this insert query to work. Is it because I have multiple data types(int, bool, strings, NoneType) that I'm inserting and I'm using `%s` ? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
class DBWork(object):
    def __init__(self, attackerip=None, victimip=None, shunlen=15, shuncount=1, shunreason=None, shunepoch=None,
                 shunerrorbool=False, shunerror=None, paloaddedepoch=None, paloremovedepoch=None,
                 lastshunlen=15):
        self.Id = None
        self.attackerip = attackerip
        self.victimip = victimip
        self.shunlen = shunlen
        self.shuncount = shuncount
        self.shunreason = shunreason
        self.shunepoch = shunepoch
        self.shundatetime = 'need to build this'
        self.shunerrorbool = shunerrorbool
        self.shunerror = shunerror
        self.paloaddedepoch = paloaddedepoch
        self.paloremovedepoch = paloremovedepoch
        self.lastshunlen = lastshunlen
        self.shunlen = shunlen
        self.newshunlen = lastshunlen * shuncount

    def HistoryInsert(self):
        insert_query = (
            "INSERT INTO `autoshun`.`shunhistory` "
            "(Id, attackerip, victimip, shunlen, shuncount, shunreason, shunepoch, shundatetime, shunerrorbool, "
            "shunerror, paloaddedepoch, paloremovedepoch) "
            "VALUES "
            "(NULL, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s );"
        )
        values = [None, self.attackerip, self.victimip, self.shunlen, self.shuncount, self.shunreason, self.shunepoch,
                  self.shundatetime, self.shunerrorbool, self.shunerror, self.paloaddedepoch, self.paloremovedepoch]
        print values
        self.cur.execute(insert_query, values)

sample = DBWork(attackerip='1.1.1.15', victimip='2.2.2.2',  shunlen=15, shuncount=1, shunreason='hax', shunerrorbool=True)

sample.DBConnect()
sample.HistoryInsert()
```

values being passed in:

`values = [None, '1.1.1.15', '2.2.2.2', 15, 1, 'hax', 'NULL', 'need to build this', False, 'NULL', 'NULL', 'NULL']`

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dobbs/PycharmProjects/autoshun/sqlobjects.py", line 102, in <module>
    sample.HistoryInsert()
  File "/home/dobbs/PycharmProjects/autoshun/sqlobjects.py", line 95, in HistoryInsert
    self.cur.execute(insert_query, values)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 164, in execute
    query = self.mogrify(query, args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 143, in mogrify
    query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: This is a typo. There are 11 `%s` placeholders in the query (`NULL` does not count), but 12 values to substitute in (`None` counts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go ahead and leave out the `id` field. MySQL will know what to do:

```
    insert_query = (
        "INSERT INTO `autoshun`.`shunhistory` "
        "(attackerip, victimip, shunlen, shuncount, shunreason, shunepoch, shundatetime, shunerrorbool, "
        "shunerror, paloaddedepoch, paloremovedepoch) "
        "VALUES "
        "(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s );"
    )

    values = [self.attackerip, self.victimip, self.shunlen, self.shuncount, self.shunreason, self.shunepoch,
              self.shundatetime, self.shunerrorbool, self.shunerror, self.paloaddedepoch, self.paloremovedepoch]
```

As is your query has a `NULL` and you're trying to pass in `None` without a parameter for that `None`.

Comment: THANKS!! that was definitely it.

Comment: Cheers, mate. Happy coding to you!